# Magento2 - After deletion of product, how to delete /avoid auto generation of placeholder (ghost) pictures?

Tags: magento2, cache, placeholder, placeholder-image

we deleted products and its associated images from

/pub/media/import

/pub/media/catalog/product/

Also from

/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/

However, the images re-appear, not the original image, but the placeholder picture.
So the link (e.g.
[www.xyz.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/99d67668879640f750d07dab82e3559f/3/8/38669-b_1-0.5x.jpg](http://www.xyz.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/99d67668879640f750d07dab82e3559f/3/8/38669-b_1-0.5x.jpg)) is still active, and does not generate a 404 page.

Thats a problem, because we want to delete the cache of search engines, e.g. with the removal tool of bing. And, if there is still a working link, the cache of bing and the original picture does not get deleted.

How to get rid of these ghost placeholder images?

Comment: are you using a CDN?

Comment: Hello, no , we just use our own server

Comment: and you flushed the FPC cache i assume, right?

Comment: yes, 
magento cache:flush and 
redis-clli flushall 
and i cleared all below /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/

Comment: If you really want to avoid that for some special files, edit .htaccess:   

<filesMatch "(image_1.jpg|image_3.jpg|image_4.jpg)">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</filesMatch>